# USB Port Linking?

Tags: windows-10, usb

My PC has two USB ports. I want to link my Android Tablet as a Slave, and a Midi Controller as a Master. The Controller has the USB-B while the Tablet has the MicroUSB.

I have no MicroUSB to USB-B type cable, so I am wondering, can my PC take the Midi Controller's input on one port, and pass it through to the second port (Act as a F/F connector), in which I will connect the second cable running to the Tablet (FLStudio).

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: It sounds like you want a USB hub, which are now often built into monitors.

Comment: @RonMaupin that still wouldn't work in this case. A USB Hub requires drivers to work and will then transfer all ports to the host which has the drivers. USB can't communicate amongst themselves.

Comment: "_A USB Hub requires drivers to work..._" No, it doesn't. It is a passive device.

Comment: @RonMaupin Please do your research. Plug and play is still a driver model. The OS may have drivers, but it still means drivers are required. Try connecting 2 devices on the receiver end of the hub and you'll find out they don't communicate at all. In fact, connect a PC on the receiver end, and you'll find out that it doesn't communicate with any of the peripals attached either.

Comment: Please don't be short, and explain what you really need. Help and solution may be available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USB hosts (aka "master" as you say, if true) cannot have Type-B connector. Type-B is for DEVICES. It is VERY LIKELY that your "MIDI-master" is just an ordinary USB device that can generate MIDI commands. You need to re-evaluate your overall link architecture.

If you really need a PC in between the MIDI and the Tablet, you will need a PC driver for your MIDI controller, then write an application that would channel the generated MIDI commands to another output device (your Android Tablet).

But it sounds like you want to just connect the MIDI to your Tablet. In this case you can reverse the role of Android Tablet into host (using so-called "OTG adapter"). The "OTG adapter has one end of Micro-B type with ID pin illegally grounded, and the other end as Type-A receptacle. This will likely make your Tablet as USB HOST. Then you should be able to connect to your MIDI-Controller using a regular Typ-A-Type-B USB cable. However, you must have a corresponding driver for the particular MIDI device, I am not sure if one exists in the Android environment.

**Addition**: if your Android Tablet supports USB HOST mode (and you want the FLstudio to use the MIDI device) but has only a micro-B connector, you can make your own single-piece cable and avoid extra "OTG adaptr". You need to buy an official Type-B to micro-A cable (it might be challenging, but this kind of cable does exist). The micro-A mold side should have the ID pin grounded, which makes Android to switch into host mode. Unfortunately, the Tablet usually has only a micro-B receptacle, so the micro-A won't fit. You just take a file, and file off two corners of the squarish micro-A plug, to make it look like micro-B type, so it will fit in. You will have a neat all-in-one adapter-cable between the Tablet and the MIDI device.

Comment: It is a Yamaha CLP-340. It has a entire IO section, ant the USB 'To Device' is a USB-B. I've used it as a MIDI controller for my PC.

Comment: @DusanDakic, then you really need to explain what is your way of use it. The CLP-340 appears to have both modes, as a USB HOST to get a pen drive (should be Type-A receptacle) and store something to it, and as USB device (as MIDI controller), with Type-B receptacle. What do you want your Android tablet to do in your "use case"?

Comment: Yes. The CLP-340 has two USB 'storage' ports and the 'USB to Device' port. I need it connected to FLStudio (a DAW) as a MIDI input. You know, FLStudio has it's own integrated thing for using MIDI devices. I only wonder can I take two USB cables in two different PC ports and just make the PC 'connect' them.

Comment: @DusanDakic, having a PC in the middle will be challenging. Do you really need a PC in between?

Comment: Well, since our PC stores where I live are dangerously under-supplied, I guess it is easier then finding a F/F USB Adapter.